# How to add points to multi-panel Lattice graphics bwplot?

Tags: r, lattice

I'm making box-and-whisker plots in Lattice with bwplot.  I want to add points for means.  I've figured out how to do this for simple plots using `panel.points`.  However, when I make a multi-panel bwplot using `+` and `outer=TRUE`, I don't know how to put different points in different panels.  This example illustrates the problem with my attempted solution, which doesn't work.  (For the sake of simplicity, it puts "x"s at arbitrary points rather than at means.)

```
# make some data:
df <- data.frame(var1=rnorm(20), var2=runif(20), cat=rep(c("Z"),20))
# cat isn't doing anything, but I couldn't get the mwe to work without it.

bwplot(var1 + var2 ~ cat, data=df, pch="|", coef=0, outer=TRUE, 
       panel=function(data, ...){
         panel.bwplot(...)
         panel.points(x=c(.5,-.5), pch="x", cex=2)
       }
      )
```

(`outer=T` combined with `var1 + var2` is what causes two panels to be created.  See below for a simpler example.)

What I get are two panels, with a box-and-whisker plot in each.  "x"s are placed over each plot.  In each panel, there is an "x" at .5 over the plot.  Rather than using -.5 in the second panel, the process starts over--Lattice grabs the first point, .5, again.

How can I get different points displayed over plots in different panels?

Thanks.

Later addition: I realize now that this issue has nothing to do with `+` and `outer=TRUE` per se.  The same behavior can be gotten using routine Lattice conditioning:

```
df <- data.frame(var1=rnorm(20), cat=rep("Z",20), cat2=rep(c("M","F"), 10))

bwplot(var1 ~ cat | cat2, data=df, pch="|", coef=0, outer=TRUE, 
           panel=function(data, ...){
             panel.bwplot(...)
             panel.points(x=c(.5,-.5), pch="x", cex=2)
           }
          )
```

Comment: Isn't there a `which.panel` function lying somewhere about? Failing that, do look at `?trellis.focus` (not just that function but the entire help page.)

Comment: No `which.panel` function, but `?trellis.focus` does look promising.  I'll investigate further.  Thanks @DWin.

Comment: `which.panel` is actually the argument name in strip.default. The halp page for the latter mentions `which.packet` as the correct function name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the accesor function `panel.number()` to choose the `x` value for each panel:

```
df <- data.frame(var1=rnorm(20), cat=rep("Z",20), cat2=rep(c("M","F"), 10))

bwplot(var1 ~ cat | cat2, data=df, pch="|", 
           panel=function(...){
             panel.bwplot(...)
             panel.points(x=c(.5,-.5)[panel.number()], 
                          pch="x", cex=2)
           }
          )
```

Edited: However, if you want to add points for means, you don't really need `panel.number`. You can define a `panel.mean` function (following the [example by Deepayan](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2005-November/081980.html)) to compute and plot them:

```
panel.mean <- function(x, y, ...) {
    tmp <- tapply(y, factor(x), FUN = mean)
    panel.points(tmp, pch = 20, ...)
}

bwplot(var1 ~ cat | cat2, data=df,
       panel=function(...){
           panel.bwplot(..., pch='|')
           panel.mean(...)
           }
)
```

Comment: Thanks!  In thinking about the matter further, after looking at [Creating a Custom Panel Function](http://casoilresource.lawr.ucdavis.edu/drupal/node/630), I realized that putting the list of extra data for the overlaid points *inside* the panel function made things unnecessarily complicated, as D.P.'s solution illustrates.  (But `panel.number()` seems very useful.) Here is a variation I like--simpler in some ways, more complicated in others: `bwplot(var1 ~ cat | cat2, data=df, panel=function(x, y, ...){panel.bwplot(x, y, ..., pch='|');panel.points(tapply(y, factor(x), FUN = mean), pch=20)})`