# How to plot points on hexbin graph in R?

Tags: r, plot, scatter-plot, points

I have two sets of data that need to plot on the same graph. A set is very large (~ 10⁶) and I want to plot with hexbin, and the other set is very small (~ 10) and I want to plot the points. How do I plot points on the hexbin?
The closer to success I got was this:

```
bin = hexbin(x, y)
plot(bin)
pushViewport(dataViewport(x, y))
grid.points(x, y)
```

I appreciate any help :)

Comment: Have you tried `points(bin)` instead of `plot()`?

Comment: @molx, I tried     points(bin) but did not work for me.

Comment: I just realized it shouldn't really work, I thought `hexbin()` created a plot, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you are using the [`hexbin`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hexbin/index.html) package...

```
library(hexbin)
library(grid)

# some data from the ?hexbin help
set.seed(101)
x <- rnorm(10000)
y <- rnorm(10000)
z <- w <- -3:3

# hexbin
bin <- hexbin(x, y)

# plot  - look at str(p)
p <- plot(bin)

# push plot viewport
pushHexport(p$plot.vp)

# add points
grid.points(z, w, pch=16, gp=gpar(col="red"))

upViewport()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi how long. Me again... You know how do this using just the command 'hexbinplot'? Now I need to be with this command. I tried everything and failed.

Comment: Hi Dani; im not really a lattice user so im not sure. I would think there is a way to use the panel argument so might be worth asking a new question ... but another (slightly easier) workaround is `hexbinplot(y~x) + xyplot(z~w, col="red", pch=16, cex=2)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ggplot package for that task, see the code below, just replace the data.frame used in the data parameter for geom_point with the one for the points you want to plot.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(hexbin)
ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price)) + stat_binhex() + geom_point(data = diamonds[c(1,10,100,1000), ], aes(carat, price), size=10, color = 'red' )
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this... it should work fine.
Just create a panel.function within your [hexbinplot](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/hexbin/docs/hexbinplot) function:

```
hexbinplot(d.frame$X ~ d.frame$Y
   ,aspect=...,cex.title=...
   ,panel=function(x, y, ...){
      panel.hexbinplot(x,y,...)
   #   panel.curve(...)        # optional stuff
   #   panel.text(...)         # optional stuff
      panel.points(x=c(25,50),y=c(100,150),pch=20,cex=3.2)
   }
)
```

take a look for instance at: [How to add points to multi-panel Lattice graphics bwplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15803149/how-to-add-points-to-multi-panel-lattice-graphics-bwplot)

Comment: Thank you, @Manuel F. :D

Comment: Please don't post dead or likely-to-die links.