# Add points in a Random Forest mtry plot

Tags: r, plot, random-forest, r-caret

I am using Random Forest with *caret* package to set the best mtry (number of prediction factors). When I plot the model to the see the variation of the RMSE with the mtry, I want to add a point into the best mtry

```
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "cv", savePred=T, number = 10)
tunegrid <- expand.grid(.mtry=seq(from=2,to=nlayers(covs_processed),by=2))
# Search for the best mtry parameter
rfmodel <- train(fm, data=dat_1963@data, method = "rf", trControl = ctrl,
                 importance=TRUE, tuneGrid=tunegrid)
```

```
plot(rfmodel,main= "Tuning RF 2018")
```

[image]

Position point:

```
rfmodel[11][[1]]$tuneValue[[1]]
```

24

```
min(rfmodel$results$RMSE)
```

2.972381

I tried adding the point with this code but I could

```
points(rfmodel[11][[1]]$tuneValue[[1]],min(rfmodel$results$RMSE),col="red")
```

The model can be found here:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tFFgxuCiJNC4PLMekBG7bgEziKGwMJmu

Comment: I trust this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31128235/how-to-add-new-dots-to-existing-lattice-plot-in-r. Try the accepted solution if it works then this is a duplicate, if not I will attempt to solve the issue and answer. In any case it would be nice if a reproducible example was provided in the post with an inbuilt data set.

Comment: I disagree about the duplication. This is a question about how to do this in relation to the data structure of this particular object type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `plot()` method in `caret` uses the `lattice` package and not base graphics so `lines` worn't work.

You can easily get results using the `ggplot` method by adding new plot layers. Here's two options:

```r
library(caret)
#> Loading required package: lattice
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
data(BloodBrain)

theme_set(theme_bw())

ctrl <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10, returnResamp = "all")
set.seed(214)
rfmodel <-
  train(
    x = bbbDescr, y = logBBB,
    method = "rf",
    preProc = "zv",
    trControl = ctrl,
    tuneGrid = data.frame(mtry = 1:10)
  )

# rfmodel$resample contains the individual RMSE values per fold. Use the
# ggplot method and add another layer with those points. 

ggplot(rfmodel) + 
  geom_point(data = rfmodel$resample, alpha = .3)
```

[image]

```r
# or add them as colored lines 
ggplot(rfmodel) + 
  geom_line(
    data = rfmodel$resample, 
    # For each resample, plot a different colored line
    aes(group = Resample, col = Resample),
    alpha = .3) + 
  # the legend here gets huge so stop it from being printed
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-04-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: thanks!! `ggplot(rfmodel) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_point(y=min(rfmodel$results$RMSE),x=rfmodel[11][[1]]$tuneValue[[1]], color="red",fill=2,
             shape = 1,size=5) }}}`